# Reading from mysql tables using pandas and named parameters in query

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I try to execute the following query

```
SELECT user_id, user_agent_id, requests 
FROM riskanalysis_user_http_ua_stats
WHERE since>= :since AND until< :until'
```

I try the following pandas code

```
sql = 'SELECT user_id, user_agent_id, requests ' \
      'FROM riskanalysis_user_http_ua_stats ' \
      'WHERE since>= :since AND until< :until'

dataframe_records = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine,
                                      params={'since':datetime_object,
                                              'until':datetime_object}
```

and I get the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'SELECT user_id, user_agent_id, requests FROM riskanalysis_user_http_ua_stats WHERE since>= :since AND until< :until'
```

I am using `pymysql` as the driver and MySQL database. How do I pass named parameters in an sql query?

EDIT 1: Corrected the parameter order but now I get the following

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':since AND until< :until' at line 1") [SQL: 'SELECT user_id, user_agent_id, requests FROM riskanalysis_user_http_ua_stats WHERE since>= :since AND until< :until'] [parameters: {'since': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'until': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 18, 0, 2, tzinfo=tzutc())}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [pandas.read_sql_query documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query),

> **params** : *list, tuple or dict, optional, default: None*
>
> List of parameters to pass to execute method. The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249's paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}

If you then look at [PEP 249's paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), you'll see many options. But the [PyMySQL's `execute` documentation](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/73c22c78d14466a5ed8029ef67ca11198234913e/pymysql/cursors.py#L157) states that

> If args is a list or tuple, %s can be used as a placeholder in the query.
>
> If args is a dict, %(name)s can be used as a placeholder in the query.

So, applying to your case, that would be:

```
sql = 'SELECT user_id, user_agent_id, requests ' \
      'FROM riskanalysis_user_http_ua_stats ' \
      'WHERE since>= %s AND until< %s'

dataframe_records = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine,
                                      params=(datetime_object, datetime_object))
```

or

```
sql = 'SELECT user_id, user_agent_id, requests ' \
      'FROM riskanalysis_user_http_ua_stats ' \
      'WHERE since>= %(since)s AND until< %(until)s'

dataframe_records = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine,
                                      params={'since':datetime_object,
                                              'until':datetime_object})
```

Comment: A tiny beginner note that stumped me to start with. If you only have one parameter, and are using the method with `(datetime_object, datetime_object)` you _NEED_ a trailing comma i.e. `(mySingleValue,)`

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.read_sql_query` expects `sql` query before the engine, and tries to parse your query as a database URI.
See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html

```
dataframe_records = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine,
      params={'since':datetime_object,'until':datetime_object}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, your driver does not recognize named placeholders using the colon syntax. The query is passed as is to MySQL, which then complains about the placeholders, since they are syntax errors. A solution is to use the SQLAlchemy [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct, which handles translating the named placeholders to a format understood by your driver:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

sql = text(sql)
dataframe_records = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine,
                                      params={'since':datetime_object,
                                              'until':datetime_object})
```